# Competition algorithm

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursion

$n$ athletes ($a_1,...,a_n$) are arranged in a line. At each time $t$, two adjacent athletes race each other. The loser is removed from the line and the winner stays in the same position. This continues until there is one athlete remaining. You have a matrix where the $(x,y)$ entry indicates gives the result if $a_x$ and $a_y$ are to race. Give an algorithm to output all possible final winners that runs in polynomial time.

The idea that I had was to iterate through each athlete (let's call this $a_i$) and have two separate competitions: one for the next ($a_{i+1}$) and one for the previous $(a_{i-1}$). I don't know if this is correct, and have not been able to prove its correctness either way. Is this correct and if so, how might I prove it?

Comment: In a racing situation, I would expect that if $a$ wins over $b$ and $b$ wins over $c$, then $a$ wins over $c$. Is this an assumption here?

Comment: @Arthur yes it is

Comment: In that case, there can only be **exactly one** possible final winner, even without the "has to race someone they're next to" limitation, and a simple recursion over the runners works (take a runner, find someone he loses to, repeat until you find the one who doesn't lose to anyone). Are you **certain** that that's an assumption in your problem?

Comment: Maybe not necessarily transitive - otherwise the final winner will always be the same regardless of the order of the races. (Just reading other comments - as Arthur says, a transitive relation makes the problem trivial).

Comment: @Arthur, ah apologies -- I meant to say that it is not transitive, so the order in which the competitions are held matters. It's a tournament bracket

Answer (score 1):

"Polynomial time" is actually pretty generous -- it lets you get away with nesting another loop of length $n$ in your program whenever you need one.

Problems like this kind naturally lend themselves to *dynamic programming* where you build up a table of answers to smaller subproblems and use those to find answers to larger subproblems, the original problem being the largest of them all.

Here, a natural shape of a subproblem would be something like:

> Is there a way entrants $a_i$ through $a_k$ can compete among themselves such that $a_j$ wins -- yes or no?

There are $O(n^3)$ such subproblems, so if only we can build an answer to one of them in polynomial time *assuming that we already know solutions to all smaller subproblems*, then we're done.

Can you see how to do that combination in $O(n^2)$ time? That would add up to an  $O(n^5)$ algorithm -- which is perhaps a bit much for *practical* use, but certainly meets the requirement of polynomial time.

Comment: I see. So, it's recursion where base case is n=3 and we keep adding elements to the athletes we've already looked at? My question, then, is suppose the next athlete the algorithm considers, call it $a_l$, is one that we know will beat $a_j$. How do you cheaply add $a_l$ to the tournament schedule so that $a_j$ still ends up winning?

Comment: @faeophyta: Recursion is harder than necessary to make work here because you need to memoize subresults. It can be useful as an opportunistic implementation technique _in practice_ but as far as my analysis here goes, it wouldn't improve the asymptotics. For the purpose of solving a "give an algorithm" exercise, just _iteratively_ fill out an $n\times n\times n$ table (or just the meaningful parts of it).

Comment: @faeophyta: (Also, your comment doesn't look like you actually read my suggestion -- it seems to have nothing at all to do with what I'm proposing).

Comment: I guess I don't understand your suggestion about doing it in $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ time. How can we make such a combination in such time?

Comment: @faeophyta: What you do in time $O(n^2)$ time is fill out _one entry_ in the table, assuming that all entries with smaller problem sizes _have already been filled out_.

Comment: @Arthur: I think you're counting something different from what I'm counting. I'm counting the total number of results we will ever need to compute (and memoise) during the entire algorithm; you seem to be counting the number of subresults that go into a single piece of the computation.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You're right. I misunderstood your intent with that question.